# Can I save Image with Complex number pixel value

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Now I get an image of fiber bundles. The pixel values indicates its angle ranging from 0 to 180 in degree. However, 0 degree and 180 degree are actually the same. So I want to use [**Euler's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), convert degree to complex number. So the 180 degree is equal to 0 degree.

I have done the Euler's formula convert in MATLAB. 
However, I don't know how to save the image with complex number pixel value using either `imwrite()` or `saveas()`. Seems that all the methods are saving the real part. Can anyone show me how to do it? Saving real numbers and imaginary numbers in two separate images will not be useful for my further processing.

Or is there any other way to correct the 0 degree and 180 degree error? Thank you all.

Comment: if 180 and 0 are considered the same, can't you just replace all 180s with 0s?

Comment: If you are working with orientation, rather than direction (180 degree range vs 360 degree range) then it's best to manipulate the double angle (so your range becomes 360 degrees). Now, functions that work on angles will do the right thing and map 0 and 180 to the same thing. -- I don't see a point in saving complex numbers, this is a trick for computation, it's easy to go back and forth to angle representation for file I/O. -- By the way, conversion of an angle to a complex number does not fix your problem, it'll map 0 and 360 to the same value.